# Xcode compile for Intel 32-64bit only

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, macos-carbon

I'm trying to compile only for 32bit and 64bit. No matter what I choose in Xcode, I can either compile for 64bit or for 32bit, 64bit and ppc. I don't want ppc at all. Anyone has any idea how to compile for 32 & 64bit only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `Architectures` setting for the project just set it explicitly to `i386` and `x86_64` rather than using the preset options.

Comment: I think you mean `x86_64`. Also, be sure the "Compile native architecture only" option is not checked.

Answer (score 3):

To compile only for i386 and x86_64 (i.e. Intel) and not PPC, do the following:

1. Go to Project|Edit Project Settings
2. Select Build tab
3. In Architectures, do
   not select any of the standard given
   options such as Standard (32/64-bit
   Universal) as these will always
   throw in ppc. Select Other... and
   add i386 and x86_64 manually.
4. In Valid Architectures, make it the same as Architectures (i.e. i386 and x86_64).

Compile. Test with lipo command in shell. (lipo -info test.app/Contents/MacOS/test) It should only say x86_64 i386 for architectures in file.

If that's not the case, then:

Go to Project|Edit Active Target "your app name" and do the same changes you did above, adding i386 and x86_64 manually.

Compile and test with lipo. It should say it's x86_64 i386 only.