# Application not supported on this type of Mac

Tags: macos, xcode5, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mavericks

I've built an Objective-C application that works on 10.9, but not on 10.5 (Mac Mini Core Duo; 32-bit).

When I open the .DMG file (on the Mini), the icon includes the 'no' symbol (circle-with-a-line through it).  When I attempt to launch the application, I get an error that reads `You can't open the application [application name here] because it is not supported on this type of Mac.`.

Project's Build settings:

- Base SDK: Latest OS X (OS X 10.9)
- Valid Architectures: i386 x86_64
- OS X Deployment Target: OS X 10.5

screenshot:

[Program not supported on this type of mac computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HLH7.png)

Relevant: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169965/xcode-compile-for-intel-32-64bit-only)

What am I missing?

Comment: You only  mention `Valid Architectures`, so what did you select for `Architectures` in `Build Settings` ? The default is `Standart Architectures`, if it is not `Universal`, then this is most likely your problem.

Comment: It was marked `Standard Architectures`.  Switching it to `Universal` fixed the problem.  Thanks for the suggestion.  If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can get the same error by double clicking on the .app inside of an unzipped .ipa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `Architecture` settings for *OS X* projects created in Xcode is `Standard Architectures` (which is - iirc - since XCode 5.1 the `x86_64`).  To build it for *32bit*  and *64bit*  you need to check which architecture is listed with the different options for `Architecture`. Currently selecting `Universal` will build a universal *32bit* and *64bit* app.

The listed architectures for `Standart Architectures` and `Universal` could change with future updates of Xcode, if Apple would e.g. start to support another Architecture for their Desktop environment.

For further details about the difference between `Valid Architectures` and `Architectures`:
[What's the difference between “Architectures” and “Valid Architectures” in Xcode Build Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12701188/1960455)